# What theorems are most important for the foundation of mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

What are the mathematical theorems which are considered as the most important for the mathematics themselves?

By importance I mean foundational to mathematics as a whole or foundational to a good chunk of mathematics.

By "foundational", I don't mean  historical founding but crucial to the current foundations of the edifice of mathematics.

I'm thinking of Gödel's incompleteness theorem for example, which is perhaps the most talked about, but I don't really understand the importance of it in practical terms and I would expect a few less well known theorems to be equally or even more important.

Comment: Define _important_.

Comment: I think you'd find it hard to think of a more foundational theorem than pythagoras'.

Comment: @Richard Can you elaborate? I know Pythagoras and his theorem, and I can see the historical importance of it. What I don't see is how it would be foundational to mathematics today. Perhaps, I need to specify that by "foundational", I don't mean  historical founding but current foundation of the edifice.

Comment: @Speakpigeon I'm not.the.right person to explain this, except to say that when you look deeply into any branch of mathematics, you'll find pythagoras at the bottom. Be that obviously trigonometry, but also algebra, number theory, group theory... and so on. When it comes right down to it, almost all maths is built up from the axioms of right angled triangles.

Comment: You can see Piergiorgio Odifreddi, [The Mathematical Century : The 30 Greatest Problems of the Last 100 Years, (Princeton UP, 2000)](https://books.google.it/books?id=cRKWBYXtvAcC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: And Martin Aigner & Günter Ziegler & Karl Hofmann, [Proofs from THE BOOK (6th ed. 2018, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=2iI9BAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @Richard: Could you please explain how e.g. group theory, which is essentially the mathematical study of symmetries, is fundamentally built upon "the axioms of right triangles"?

Comment: @Richard That's just not true. I'd love to hear, for example, how group theory (or computability theory, or algebraic topology, or ...) is ultimately founded on right triangles.

Comment: The sense of "foundational" you have in mind does not exist anymore, one can "build" mathematics on multiple alternative basic notions (sets, categories, types), or none, and switch bases at will, see [Azzouni Is there still a Sense in which Mathematics can have Foundations?](https://as.tufts.edu/philosophy/sites/all/themes/asbase/assets/documents/azzouniStillASense.pdf) (the answer is no). So you will have to come up with a different interpretation of "most important" to make this answerable. Perhaps, most talked about, or having most versatile applications/connections to different fields.

Comment: @Conifold I don't know about that - there are certainly results which apply to any plausible foundation for mathematics. And "crucial to the **current** foundations of the edifice of mathematics" *(emph. mine)* helps limit the scope further: although many foundations are possible, there are only a few that are actually seriously considered at the moment, and certainly ZFC takes the cake for most standard. So I see no problem with "foundational" here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ZFC is just a convenient scheme for organizing traditional fields whose "foundational" specifics (such as the axioms and "reconstructions" like functions as ordered pairs) are mostly ignored in the practice of those fields. Nor do many take seriously the "foundational" nature of the axioms themselves, as platonic truths, or laws of thought, or some such. It is more of a mathematical OED than foundations (which it was thought more as back in 1950-70s).

Comment: @Conifold "Nor do many take seriously the "foundational" nature of the axioms themselves, as platonic truths, or laws of thought, or some such." That's not the only way to have foundational significance - the role as a lingua franca is also a form of foundations, albeit a pragmatic one. And it is definitely active in this respect (see e.g. the study of homotopy type theory as an alternative). Regardless, there are certainly foundational topics in mathematics (the basic properties of first-order logic, for example), so I strongly disagree - again - with your claim.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Isn't the purpose of OED to establish lingua franca as well? I suppose one could call its content the standard/pragmatic foundations of English, but that is not how the word ["foundations"](https://www.iep.utm.edu/found-ep/) is usually used in philosophy (in either compositional or justificatory sense). Is the disagreement just over the use of the word?

Comment: @Alexis this is something I heard Roger Penrose say. And if anyone knows anything about symmetry, it's him. As I say I don't know how, but pythagoras' theorem if foundational, either directly or historically in pretty much all of mathematics. It's where mathematics (as opposed to arithmetic) began.

Comment: @Richard: i'd be interested in the exact quote from Penrose; my guess is that you're misremembering or misunderstanding what he said. i say this because based on my own knowledge of the basics of group theory, topology, set theory, category theory and mathematical foundations (such as ZFC), your claim that "when you look deeply into any branch of mathematics, you'll find pythagoras at the bottom" is simply incorrect. (For example: try to find a mention of the word 'triangle' in [the Wikipedia page on 'group theory'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory)).

Comment: @Richard: Yes, Pythagoras' theorem was a seminal moment in humanity's development of mathematics, but to say that it's directly  foundational in "pretty much all of mathematics" is a grand claim that requires more substantial support than "I don't know how".

Comment: @Alexis like most things in my back catalogue of anecdotes and quotes, I remember the thing, but not where i heard it. It was at the back end of a youtube video in which he was discussing the gauge groups.

Answer (score 5):

*One person's foundations are another person's pointless pedantics. What follows is my own view of the foundational side of mathematics. Many of these results are not widely known among mathematicians, and so their foundational significance is definitely up for debate - is it really important if nobody needs it? - but to my mind these are results which tell us something important about the **character** of mathematics: they're not necessarily what makes it tick, but they say something about the sound that ticking makes.*

Gödel's incompleteness theorem is definitely fundamental - it tells us what we can hope for from a "foundation for mathematics." A lot of this is taken for granted, but pre-Gödel the idea of a "nice" axiom system which would suffice to (at least in principle) resolve all mathematical questions was a reasonable dream. Post-Gödel, I think the theorem suffers from its in-retrospect-obviousness, but even if we just think of it as the confirmation of a perfectly reasonable intuition about the limits of mathematical reasoning (which some people at the time certainly had) it's still important in that respect. [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) also deserves mention here, since it emphasizes the fact that *representation* in the language of arithmetic is the real issue here as opposed to the more-obviously-intriguing *self-reference* (which per the [Diagonal Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma) isn't really much of an issue).

So as to some other foundational theorems, let's start with the "classical" ones - gauging how first-order logic behaves:

- Gödel's [**Completeness Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem). Roughly speaking, there are two natural notions of "entailment" in logic: *semantic entailment* (= "p is true in every structure satisfying the axioms G," LaTeX code "$G\models p$") and *syntactic entailment* (= "there is a formal deduction of p from G," - LaTeX code "$G\vdash p$"). In general there's no a priori reason for the two notions to coincide; while it's easy to make sure that G *syntactically* entails p only if G *semantically* entails p (just make sure that your proof rules "make sense"), there's no reason to believe a priori that a given proof system *fully* captures the semantics. Keep in mind that a formal proof is a *finite object*, but even a finite theory G might not have any computable models. However, Gödel showed that we can in fact find a completely satisfying proof system. This is hugely foundational, as it justifies the value of formal proofs in the first place; to my mind it is also quite surprising - much more so than the incompleteness theorem - [especially in light of the difficulty of telling whether a *specific* structure satisfies a given sentence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099531/how-to-verify-satisfialibility-in-a-model-confusions-with-g%C3%B6dels-completeness).
- The [**(Downward) Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem). Continuing our analysis of first-order logic, the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem gauges the role of set theory in pure logic. There are other more technical results continuing this theme - e.g. the Mostowski and Shoenfield absoluteness theorems, especially in light of [the Levy collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) - but this one is where it all starts.
- The [**Compactness Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem). This says quite simply that the semantic entailment relation - see above - is "finitary:" if G semantically entails p then H semantically entails p for some *finite* subset H of G. This is an immediate corollary of the completeness theorem (since proofs can only use finitely many axioms), but doesn't need to be proved this way, and is really important on its own so in my opinion worth mentioning separately.
- Now a lesser-known one. We frequently talk about justifying our *axiom system*, but we should also care about what distinguishes our *underlying logic* from other logical systems we could (at least in principle) employ. [**Lindström's theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%27s_theorem) gives a characterization of first-order logic: it is a maximal logic (with respect to expressive power) with the compactness and Löwenheim-Skolem properties. So in some sense first-order logic gives an upper bound for how strong a logical system can be without bringing infinities into the picture in one way or another.
- And finally, another lesser-known one (or pair): the characterization of satisfaction of a sentence in a structure via [**Skolem functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#How_Skolemization_works) and of elementary equivalence between structures via the [**Ehrenfeucht-Fraïsse Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game). These set the stage for the "game semantics" approach to understanding logic(s). I personally consider this a fundamental aspect of what logic is - structures, proofs, *and games* - but I recognize this is fairly personal opinion; that said, [here's a neat application of proofs-as-games language to algebraic geometry](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.0163.pdf).

---

OK, what if we look further afield - e.g. from what logic is/can be to sets, computations, ...?

Well, ultimately we run into a question of what "foundational" means. For example, what about results which impact how we think about mathematics in a deep way? The idea of Galois connections, for example, is absolutely fundamental to modern mathematics; is the [fundamental theorem of Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory) therefore fundamental, since it firmly establishes a place for these?

I'll tentatively say "no." With that in mind, here are a couple other theorems I consider foundational, organized by subject:

- **Set Theory**: [**Cantor's work**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) established that we can in fact talk about infinite sets in a mathematically coherent way. That's *huge* in my opinion. Meanwhile, I *don't* consider hugely important topics like forcing or [inner model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model_theory) to be truly foundational (although some will disagree with me on this), and I'm not really sold on ZFC as anything more than a convenient historical choice. The only other theorem in set theory I'd consider truly foundational is [**Russell's paradox**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox): Gödel's incompleteness theorem puts limits on what we can expect from a foundational *theory*, but Russell established a limit on what mathematical *language* can treat appropriately. With the example of "naive properties" *(and see my comments below this answer for a bit more comment on that)*, Russell's paradox raises the general question of whether *fundamentally self-contradictory* ideas can also be *meaningful mathematical* ideas, and I think that's fascinating.
- **Computability Theory**: Similarly to the situation with the Completeness Theorem, the existence of a satisfactory (in the general opinion, anyways) formalization of the intuitive notion of computation should be wildly surprising - in the modern world it's not, in light of computers, but that's a shame. Cantor's diagonal argument establishes the existence of non-computable sets, but the [**unsolvability of the halting problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) establishes the existence of *interesting* ones. [**Kleene's identification of the T-predicate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate) connects computability with definability in arithmetic - unsurprisingly in light of Gödel's representation of *primitive recursive* functions, but still important - and while it's not a *theorem* I think the formal definition of [**oracle computation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) (or rather, the existence of such) is also foundational.
- **Category theory**: I do in fact consider the notion of category (and the attendant concepts - functor, natural transformation, adjunction, universal property, ...) to be truly foundational: they tell us more about what mathematics, as we do it at least, *is*. That said, I don't know of many *theorems* that I'd consider foundational (I suspect this is more a "me" problem). [The Yoneda lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) is an obvious candidate, but I'm not sure I really consider it "foundational" (see my comments above). Instead I'll go for [**the non-concreteness of homotopy**](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/homotopy-is-not-concrete/); I'm not really overwhelmed by the result itself, but the idea that there are limitations to how the universe of sets can capture other mathematical "universes" - however technical - is one which thrills me.

---

The above surely reveals many biases on my part - but hopefully I've succeeded in painting a "foundational picture" which is, if nothing else, nontrivially interesting.

Comment: *The following expands on a now-removed part of this answer, which I've decided wasn't of central importance but still deserves mention:* It's worth pointing out just how lethal Russell's paradox was to naive set theory. It's a reasonable instinct to think that we can save naive set theory by passing to a paraconsistent logic (where contradictions are allowed without necessarily trivializing everything). However, this **won't** actually save us here! This is essentially because we can blend Russell's paradox with *Curry's paradox*. (cont'd)

Comment: Reasoning in naive set theory, let p be any proposition we want to prove. Let X be the set {a: if a is an element of a, then p}. We have "if X is in X, then if X is in X then p" - and this in turn gives "if X is in X, then p." But that implies X is in X, which therefore gives us p. Unwinding this, we get that it's very hard indeed to formulate a version of naive set theory that doesn't explode immediately: contradiction has nothing to do with it, we're getting into trouble at the level of *modus ponens itself*! So that's why I said "**fundamentally** self-contradictory" above - it *really* is!

Comment: There are paraconsistent logics that block the Curry paradox explosion, see [Meyer-Routley-Dunn, 1979](https://academic.oup.com/analysis/article-abstract/39/3/124/217500?redirectedFrom=fulltext). Your version will be blocked by any relevant logic, since p has nothing to do with X. The trouble is not so much with modus ponens but with its use on the material conditional. "Naive" reasoning does not use it, perhaps explaining why Frege and Cantor overlooked the paradoxes.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry, just saw this. Of course you're right, and I was unclear. I didn't mean to say that *no* paraconsistent logic gets around it, only that the most naive retreat to paraconsistent logic isn't enough. That said, re: "The trouble is not so much with modus ponens but with its use on the material conditional," I would consider trouble with the use of modus ponens on the material conditional to *be* trouble with modus ponens, but of course that's an aesthetic claim.

Comment: We intuitively trust modus ponens based on experience with natural reasoning, which is highly compartmentalized. The material conditional erases the restrictions and universalizes consequence, which is technically handy, but then we do not really have a reason to expect that modus ponens should still work. It is less of a paradox and more of a bait and switch at the heart of many logical paradoxes. I guess you are right about aesthetics, but the blame is usually placed on the contrivance, and not on that which it spoils.

Answer (score 1):

One theorem I find to be particularly important is

> Topos theory = Set theory = Type theory = Higher order logic

I'm phrasing this a little glibly, of course; each of these have various precise statements and various generalizations.

The reason I find these equivalences to be important, because it tells us vast swaths of different approaches to mathematics that superficially seem profoundly different are, in fact, all basically the same underlying ideas dressed up in different language. Among the consequences are:

- Having different language and perspectives *is very useful*: each perspective on the foundations clarifies different aspects of mathematics and has its own advantages and disadvantages.
- It unifies a number of things that have been historically divisive, freeing us collectively from having to dwell on them. For example, it demonstrates there is no essential difference between the set-theoretic "completed infinity" of natural numbers isolated from the mathematical universe by the principle of comprehension and the type-theoretic "potential infinity" of natural numbers constructed inductively by starting from zero and applying the successor operations